# How to change Finder as the default File manager in MacOS?

Tags: macos, finder

For e.g, when I am uploading an image for a webpage in chrome, and use "Upload from Computer", it automatically opens up Finder. I want to use an alternative (say CommanderOne or PathFinder) to be the default for this.

Comment: What do you mean with "opens up Finder"? Do you want to change the File Picker dialog you get in such cases?

Comment: Yes, I want the "File Picker" to be a different program.

Comment: DefaultFolderX is designed to do just that: https://stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t change the default file manager on macOS. It’s hooked too deeply into the rest of the system.

The only way for you to be able to have a different file picking dialog in Chrome is if Google made significant changes to support changing it. This won’t happen.